# i got the bad access exception when the function is called with delay

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

i want to search the data in the array and refresh the table view but when i called the delay function i got the BAD ACCESS exception and can not work.
but i want this function after some delay here is my code this is my complete class

```
 #import "ViewController.h"
    #import "DBHandler.h"
    #import "placeDC.h"

    @interface ViewController ()

    @end

    @implementation ViewController

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];


        DBHandler *db = [[DBHandler alloc]init];
        dataArray=[db autoComplete];
        isSearching=0;

        myTableView.hidden=YES;
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        dispalyPlaces=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:dataArray];
    }

    - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
    {
        [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }



    #pragma mark - Table view data source

    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    {
        return 1;
    }

    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
        if(isSearching)
        {
            return  [dispalyPlaces count];
        }
        else
            return [dataArray count];
    }

    - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        return 44;
    }



    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {

        /* FOR SIMPLE CELL */
        static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyCell";

        UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
        placeDC *palcedc;

      //  NSLog(@"%d",isSearching);
        if(isSearching)
        {
            palcedc = [dispalyPlaces objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
        }
        else
        {
            palcedc  = [dataArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
        }
        cell.textLabel.text = palcedc.placeNmae;

            return cell;
    }


    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {




    }

    -(void)delayCall{
        for (placeDC *placedc in dataArray) {
            NSRange  r ;

            r = [placedc.placeNmae rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
                    if (r.location!=NSNotFound) {
                [dispalyPlaces addObject:placedc];
            }
        }
      }

    - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
    {
        [self.view endEditing:YES];
    }

    - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{
        if ([string length]==0) {

            [dispalyPlaces removeAllObjects];
            [dispalyPlaces addObjectsFromArray:dataArray];
            isSearching = 0;

            myTableView.hidden=YES;
        }
        else{
            isSearching=1;
            searchText=textField.text;
        [dispalyPlaces removeAllObjects];
            myTableView.hidden=NO;

            [self performSelector:@selector(delayCall) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];

           // [self delayCall];

    //        for (placeDC *placedc in dataArray) {
    //            NSRange  r ;
    //            NSLog(@"%@",placedc.placeNmae);
    //            
    //            
    //       r = [placedc.placeNmae rangeOfString:textField.text options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
    //    
    //            
    //            if (r.location!=NSNotFound) {
    //                [dispalyPlaces addObject:placedc];
    //            }
    //        }
           [myTableView reloadData];

        }
        NSLog(@"%d",[dispalyPlaces count]);
        return YES;

    }


    //- (void)searchBar:(UITextField *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText{
    //
    //    if ([txtSearch.text length]==0) {
    //        myTableView.hidden=YES;
    //    }
    //
    //    else{
    //        myTableView.hidden=NO;
    //        [dispalyPlaces removeAllObjects];
    //        for (placeDC *palce in dataArray) {
    //            NSRange  r ;
    //            
    //            r = [palce.placeNmae rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
    //        }
    //
    //    }
    //    
    //}
    //
    //- (void)dealloc {
    //    [myTableView release];
    //    [txtSearch release];
    //    [super dealloc];
    //}
    @end
```

Comment: Show also the ivars and how you initialize them.

Comment: Please show the crash report, in particular on which line the code crashes.

Comment: io edited the question plz replay

Comment: r = [placedc.placeNmae rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
                    if (r.location!=NSNotFound) {
                [dispalyPlaces addObject:placedc];

Comment: your viewDidload : [db autocomplete] ? return an array? what about the ownership of this array? and also dataArray how you retain it? Will be interesting how you define dataArray

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please go to product>edit Schem>diagonist>enable zombie objects

run project and try to crash now. It will give you information that which object caused crash. Review that object and your error will be resolved